# jQuery.ajax() log the HTTP request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, logging, httprequest

I have a function that sends an HTTP POST request and i want to log it for debugging purposes. Here is the function:

```
function serverRequest(URL, DATA, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
        contentType: "text/xml",
        processData: false,
        data: DATA,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            callback(response);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            callback(null);
        }
    });
}
```

How can i log the whole HTTP POST request (HTTP Header + data), as soon as it is send?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using chrome or firefox you can see the request in developper tools. For chrome, just hit Ctrl+Shift+J and open the network tab.

Comment: I don't see my request. I just see in the console tab what i am logging. Isn't there any way to log the request just like i log the response?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Look for the tab "**Network**" (*not* the **Console** tab) on your Developer Tools (Ctrl+Shift+J) if you are using Chorme, or anythig similar if you are using another browser.

Even after that, if you want to log the XHtmlRequest, you can always do (if your browser supports console.log):

```
var xhr = $.ajax(...);
console.log(xhr);
```

Hope I've helped.

Comment: fwiw `console.log(xhr);` prints `[object Object]

Comment: Wrap the `xhr` as such `JSON.stringfy(xhr)` to see the plain text representation of the JSON object.