# Failing ajax function and some advice on how to debug jquery/ajax calls

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am working on a project for a crm(just to learn) and i have trouble with an ajax function.

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <label>Name</label>
    <select class="named" name ="named" id="named" onchange="userData('<?php echo $client['client_name']; ?>')">
        <?php
        $clients=mysqli_query($db->db,"SELECT client_name FROM clients");
        foreach($clients as $client): ?>
        <option value="<?= $client['client_name'];?>"><?= $client['client_name']; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>

</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Location</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="locationd" id="locationd"/>
```

and the ajax function

```
function userData(name){
    alert('debug');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType:'JSON',
        url: 'adminAction.php',
        data: 'action_type=clientdata&name='+name,
        success:function(data){
            alert('debug');
            $('#locationd').val(data.client_location);
        }
    });
}
```

its a mysql generated dropdown and on change it should fill the location input with this clients location but it doesnt work.Apache returns no errors but i am kinda noob especially when it comes to debugging ajax calls(how the ** can i see what data it sends and receives ? :D).Thanks for your help in advance !!
I post the adminaction.php code too

```
if($_POST['action_type'] == 'clientdata'){
            $tblName = 'clients';
            $conditions['where'] = array('client_name' =>$_POST['named']);
            $conditions['return_type'] = 'single';
            $client = $db->getRows($tblName,$conditions);
            echo json_encode($client);
            $tblName  = 'clients_contact';
```

for anyone interested i fixed it like that

```
function userData(){
            userData = $("#named").serialize()+'&action_type=clientdata';
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType:'JSON',
                url: 'adminAction.php',
                data: userData,
                success:function(data){
                    $('#locationd').val(data.client_location);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: can you please add your ajax code and error here?

Comment: Open Developer console (F12) in Chrome or (Ctrl+Shift+I) in Firefox, and then go to Network tab to see the request and response

Comment: First try `data: {action_type: clientdata, name: name},`

Comment: [This solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12052515/6693643) and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813346/jquery-ajax-log-the-http-request) might help

Comment: You should add an error handler in your ajax function and you should post the contents of `adminAction.php`.

Comment: @RiggsFolly nah man that didnt work.it seems it doesnt send any data in the name variable..probably mesed something

Comment: Also note that you are not actually using the value of the selected option in your ajax call, you will always send the same data in your ajax request.

Comment: You are attempting to use `onchange="userData('<?php echo $client['client_name']; ?>')"` this variable before you actually execute the query to fetch it.

Comment: You are not fetching the data from the query you execute anyway `mysql_fetch_assoc()` for example

Comment: Basically its a mess _man_.

Comment: You are trying to put ONE clients name in the `<select>` but the dropdown can contain MORE THAN ONE clients names

Comment: Can I suggest you write a simple <form> with a submit button and see how that works before attempting to move on to AJAX

Comment: what is `.val()` (ajax function last sensible line).

Comment: VTC as TYPO and moving on

Comment: you was right i fixed my data fetching but i dont understand why onchange on empty variable is problematic since the event is called after the dropdown is being populated.VTC as TYPO?.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the main mistake with ajax calls is, that they don't send the expected requests or don't receive the expected results. Both of those can at least be seen with almost every decent browser by:

- pressing F12,
- going to the network tab and then
- check the requests that are made from this point on (sometimes a reload of the page is necessary).

Also: almost every decent browser has a javascript debugger somewhere, where you can set breakpoints and step through your code, while watching all the variables of interest.

Answer (score 0):

If your AJAX output is in JSON format you can use `$.parseJSON(result)` to decode your JSON data to Array.

Comment: As the `dataType` is set to `json`, it will be parsed automatically.